# Why c++ map value don't update for same key?

Tags: c++, stl

Here is my code:

```
map <pair<int,int> ,string> m; 
m.insert(make_pair(1,2),"imtiaz");//making key value pair
m.insert(make_pair(8,3),"moin");
m.insert(make_pair(1,2),"izm");

cout<<m[make_pari(1,2)]<<endl; //print value for key 1,2

output:
imtiaz
```

We know if we insert a value for existing key in map, it will update the value.Here for same key (1,2) I insert two values "imtiaz" and "izm".So,latest value "izm" should print here.What is the wrong here?

Comment: That is the behavior for insert. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) ***Inserts element(s) into the container, if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key.***

Comment: what function should use for insert?

Comment: @ImtiazMehedi Just use `m[{1,2}]="izm";`.

Comment: Use insert for insert. operator[] for update

Comment: "We know if we insert a value for existing key in map, it will update the value." we know wrong, unfortunately :( We should base our knoweldge on the documentation which clearly says otherwise..

Comment: One reason why `insert` does not update the map is that we can write code like this without any `if` logic to test if a key exists:  `std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m;... m.insert({1, std::vector<int>()}).first->second.push_back(10);` which basically says "add a 10 to the vector of int for key value 1".  The vector will either be created for the new key 1 and 10 added to the vector, or it will add 10 to the existing vector in the map for key 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the intended behavior of `insert` to not overwrite existing entries in the map.

Use [`insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) (C++17) for the behavior you expect. In older C++ versions, use assignment with `operator[]` to update (or insert) an element.

So why was `insert_or_assign` introduced? From the link above:

> insert_or_assign returns more information than operator[] and does not require default-constructibility of the mapped type.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) does not modify an element that is already in the map. Rather, it inserts new elements. The return type allows to check it the insertion was successful (i.e there wasn't already an element with the same key) or not.

You add a new element *or* modify an existing element with `operator[]`:

```
m[make_pair(1,2)] = "izm";
```

Comment: You can also "insert" an element with `operator[]`

Comment: @Caleth Yes, kind of. You create a value-initialized one, then assign it a value. But I edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

std::map::insert does not update the existing elements. you can use insert_or_assign or operator [].

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `std::map::insert` (the one that you use) is like this:

```
template< class T >
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(T&& v);
```

As you can see in the signature, the return value is a `std::pair` and the second element of this pair is a bool, showing if `v` has been inserted into map or not.